# Laravel 6 View Composer Target Class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

my Composer Service Provider is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\ViewComposers\DashboardComposer;
use App\companies;
use App\user;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('layouts.dashboard', DashboardComposer::class);
    }
}
```

my DashboardComposer is as follows:

```
<?



namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\companies;
use App\user;


class DashboardComposer
{

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $company = companies::findOrFail($user->companyID);
        $view->with(['user' => $user, 'company' => $company]);
     }
}
```

my config/app.php is as follows:

```
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,
```

],

my file structure is as follows:

[image: file structure image]

my error as is follows:

[image: my error]

I am at a loss as to what I have done wrong. I used PHP artisan to make the provider and the composer, i have done `composer dumpautoload`, I have cleared all the caches, I have double and triple checked my spelling, I feel like I maybe just missing a step to register the class or something but I just don't know for sure and i'm tired of guessing.

Any advice would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try running `composer du` in the root of your project.

Comment: your opening tag for the Dashboard composer is `<?` instead of `<?php`, I am fairly certain this is invalid in PHP 7

Comment: That was it missing php, thank you so much, please post it as an answer so I can check it and give it an upvote

Comment: @AnthonyMoore done, thanks and glad I could help! The little typos are always the hardest to find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your opening tag on the Composer class is `<?`, should be `<?php`. Short tags are disabled by default, so this is not a valid opening tag in PHP 5/7 unless you turn it on in php.ini